# Access picamera from SSH and VNC on Windows

Tags: ssh, camera, raspberry-pi2, vnc

I read in the [Raspberry Pi Official Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/getting-started-with-picamera/worksheet/) that you cannot preview the `picamera` using `SSH` and `VNC`. The doc states:

> Note that the camera preview only works when a monitor is connected to
>   the Pi, so remote access (such as SSH and VNC) will not allow you to
>   see the camera preview.

But, I have googled and I have found a tweak to preview `picamera` on PC running on `Ubuntu`. Here is the [link](http://zacharybears.com/low-latency-raspberry-pi-video-streaming/). The tutorial uses **`NetCat`** on `Ubuntu`.

I cannot find **`NetCat`** for my Windows machine. Is there any way possible to do what I want on Windows.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/14501/113004

Comment: @OrangeDog I can't find a good answer in the post you provided. It's a good post though.

Comment: All you are asking is what is the netcat equivalent on Windows

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, If there is an alternative to netcat on Windows, that would be great.u

Comment: Then how does the link I gave you not answer the question?

Comment: @OrangeDog so many different solutions, all of these are not tested on Windows 10. Even there is no accepted answer. I don't even know which answer to choose.

Comment: So you haven't bothered to try a single one of them? There's nothing more we can do for you.

Comment: @OrangeDog why are you mad at me like that!!. I tried 1st and 3rd answer, none worked for me. The idea of installing another software like `WireShark` is good but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @OrangeDog The `netcat` works, but I have no output on my PC!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! On your raspberry pi install xRDP

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Then log in from your Windows and open Remote Desktop Connection/Viewer and proceed.

Note: it is vital to update and upgrade packages first. Also ensure you have the latest firmware.